# How can I open a port in iptables for RMI access

Tags: linux, rmi, iptables

I'm trying to connect from my Java application to a development server that has port 8088 closed which is used for RMI. I appreciate any help on how to open that port.

Comment: Can you change 8088 to something more standard (e.g., 1099)?  You might also want to check the sockets that are opened - some may be anonymous (i.e., random numbers).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687/how-do-i-ensure-that-rmi-uses-only-a-specific-set-of-ports

Answer (score 3):

Assuming

- you want to allow access from everywhere
- you want to allow access via the first ethernet device (eth0)
- you want to allow access to port 8088 using tcp

then you could try running

> iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8088 -j ACCEPT

as root.

Answer (score 0):

Slicehost have some good documentation on setting up iptables on Ubuntu:

- http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/25/ubuntu-hardy-setup-page-1
- http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/9/2/mail-server-opening-ports-in-the-firewall