# How to force or predict the second open port of jstatd?

Tags: java, performance, rmi, jstatd

If you want to start [`jstatd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html) on a specific port for its RMI registry, you can pass `-p` parameter for this.

But the problem is that it opens a second random port (called "anonymous port" in java) which causes problem for writing firewall rules or to use JVisualVM to connect to a remote `jstatd` running in a Docker container.

If you look at [`jstatd` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/tools/jstatd/Jstatd.java/#142), you'll see that it is calling [`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteHost, 0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject(java.rmi.Remote,%20int)) which will open a new "anonymous port" which seems to be random.

Is there a way to force this last port to a fixed one, or a way to predict which one will be chosen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ensure that RMI uses only a specific set of ports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687/how-do-i-ensure-that-rmi-uses-only-a-specific-set-of-ports)

Comment: Actually it will cause the newly exported object to reuse a previously used port, such as the Registry port, unless there are socket factory conflicts. Do you have evidence? or is this question just based on this misreading?

Comment: @EJP: I don't really understand your comment... My question is based on the fact that when launching `jstatd` another port is opened (as well as the RMI registry port) and if you don't also forward this port in a firewall rule, then JVisualVM (for example) will not be able to access this remote server...

Comment: @EJP I also can confirm that it is an "anonymous port" which is opened in that case by looking at the source & documentation of `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote obj)` which will use a `new UnicastServerRef(true)` which calls `this(0)` in the constructor (so its setting local port to `0` which is said "anonymous port" in multiple location in the sources & docs). So it is nearly equivalent to calling `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote obj, 0)` (the only difference is the `forceStubUse` which will be set to `false` in `UnicastServerRef`).

Comment: @AnthonyO. If you dig a little deeper you will find the port-sharing logic. It's there.

Comment: @EJP: I dug and found nothing about how to predict the port that will be used by specifying an "anonymous port"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no easy way to predict which concrete port will be opened by using an anonymous port.

But I found a rewrite of `jstatd` called "[jakestatd](https://github.com/jdonofrio728/jakestatd)" which will force the 3 ports (because at last, I discovered that `jstatd` actually opens 3 ports and not 2 as I first thought) that `jstatd` uses.

As it was not enough for me because I needed to control those ports, I wrote [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) that answer this exact question (as well as others), so now I can control thos ports using (inside ejstatd's folder):

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="-pr 2222 -ph 2223 -pv 2224"
```

Here the 3 ports that will be opened will be `2222`, `2223` and `2224`, and the RMI registry will be available at port `2222`.